# How to check if an element with id exists or not in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm generating a div dynamically and I've to check whether a dynamically generated div exists or not ? How can I do that?

Currently I'm using the following which does not detects the div generated dynamically. It only detects if there is already an element with the id contained in the HTML template.

```
$(function() {
    var $mydiv = $("#liveGraph_id");
    if ($mydiv.length){
        alert("HHH");
    }
});
```

How can I detect the dynamically generated div?

Comment: Do you have control over the div that is generated automatically? If so perform the step when the element is added

Comment: by `detect the dynamically generated div`, what do you exactly want to detect?

Comment: you need to execute it after the element is created

Comment: If you want to know when it's added to the `document`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11546242 might be useful. http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver

Comment: try if ($mydiv.length>0)

Comment: place that code in a function and give it a directive to check. You can user setInterval, or an event listener, etc. But hte method you have is correct. That will detect and serve your needs

Comment: Well, I'm trying to generate the div like this in python `portlet_div_str += "<div class='portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all' id='widget_"+widget` and then sending it to the browser, and the above js function(provided in the question) is not able to check whether the element exists or not. How do I do it?

Comment: In your case you can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/9FW9Z/ using Mutation observer, but it is not supported in all the browsers.

Comment: @PSL - Not working. since it is not supported by all the browsers, hence cannot take it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: @JoaoPalma - Tried. Not Working.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yaa I know I need to execute it after the element has been added and there lies my question. How do I do that?

Comment: @KaiQing - Can you please provide me with a demo?

Comment: jonathan just did. alvaro also gave an example of an event listener

Answer (score 11):

If mutation observes aren't an option due to their [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver), you'll have to involve the code that's actually inserting the `<div>` into the `document`.

One options is to use a custom event as a [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe).

```
$(document).on('document_change', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('liveGraph_id')) {
        // do what you need here
    }
});
```

```
// without a snippet to go on, assuming `.load()` for an example
$('#container').load('/path/to/content', function () {
    $(this).trigger('document_change');
});
```

Comment: What does path to content means?

Comment: @user1162512 It's just a sample URL path. You mentioned in a comment that the `<div>` is written in Python, so assumed Ajax was involved in retrieving it.

Comment: No. Ajax is not involved in this particular case. I'm just forwarding this string of HTML elements onto the template when the page first loads or if I refresh the page. This is how I 'm doing. `return render_to_response('dashboard/widget_dashboard.html',{'HTMLstr':HTMLstr}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))` and in the template I'm calling that string of HTML elements by `{% if HTMLstr %}        
            {% autoescape off %}{{ HTMLstr }}{% endautoescape %}
         {% else %}`

Answer (score 3):

If it is added dinamically, you have to test again. Let's say, a click event

```
$("#element").click(function()
{
    if($("#liveGraph_id").length)
        alert("HHH");
});
```

Comment: Test whenever you want to check if it exists.
`$(function() {...})` is executed after the DOM has been loaded. If you add an element later, you must run the test again. (Not necesarily on a click event)

Comment: why was this downvoted? It look slike it's just an example of an event listener

Answer (score 0):

How you inserting your dynamic generated div?

It works if you do it in following way:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'liveGraph_id';
div.innerHTML = "i'm dynamic";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
if ($(div).length > 0) {
    alert('exists'); //will give alert
}
if ($('#liveGraph_id').length > 0) {
    alert('exists'); //will give alert
}
if ($('#liveGraph_id_extra').length > 0) {
    alert('exists'); //wont give alert because it doesn't exist.
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJsRM/).

Comment: Well, I'm already aware of this, but I'm not creating the div in the jQuery but in the python(backend). Here is how I'm doing. `portlet_div_str += "<div class='portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all' id='widget_"+widget` and then sending it to the browser, and the above js function(provided in the question) is not able to check whether the element exists or not. How do I do it?

Comment: but how you adding it in document? without adding you can't check if its exist or not.

Comment: I call it in the template using django syntax `{{{% autoescape off %}{{ portlet_div_str }}{% endautoescape %}}}`

Answer (score 0):

Just for interest, you can also use a live collection for this (they are provided as part of the DOM). You can setup a collection of all divs in the page (this can be done in the head even before the body is loaded):

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Any div with an id is available as a named property of the collection, so you can do:

```
if (allDivs.someId) {
  // div with someId exists
}
```

If the ID isn't a valid identifier, or it's held in a variable, use square bracket notation. Some play code:

```
<button onclick="
  alert(!!allDivs.newDiv);
">Check for div</button>
<button onclick="
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'newDiv';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
">Add div</button>
```

Click the *Check for div* button and you'll get `false`. Add the div by clicking the *Add div* button and check again—you'll get `true`.

Comment: Just love those drive–by down votes. Ok, no jQuery (hence "just for interest"), but what else?

Answer (score 0):

is very simple as that

```
   if(document.getElementById("idname")){
//div exists 

}
```

or

```
    if(!document.getElementById("idname")){
//  don't exists
}
```